# make child control visible=true when parent control visiblity=false in c# win forms

Tags: visible

I am working with a ToolStripMenuItem in winforms.Setting

```
splitLineItemToolStripMenuItem.Visible = true;
```

does not make it visible as the container ContextMenuStrip visiblity is false;
I understand that if container visibility is false,child element cannot be set to true.

IS there any workaround to make it visible.

Comment: What exactly do you hope to achieve by having a menu item visible when the menu itself isn't?

Comment: VS intellisense shows that menu is not visible,but when code completes menu is visible with all toolstrip items disabled.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with a class inheriting from `System.Web.UI.Control`. I think a workaround to your situation is:

```
public class MyToolStripMenuItem : ToolStripMenuItem 
{
    public override bool Visible {get;set;}
}
```

...and then use `MyToolStripMenuItem` instead of `ToolStripMenuItem`.